# Mulitple Classes + For loops + static lists

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 classes....`Station_Spawner`, `Game_Manager` and `Player_EnemyArrow`.

In Station_Spawner I have a co routine to handle how many enemies are spawned and the time between them being spawned.

```
IEnumerator SpawnShips(int numofenemies, int timebetweenspawn)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numofenemies; i++)
    {
        GameObject enemy =  Instantiate(Enemy, ShipSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        enemy.name = "Enemy" + i;

        Game_Manager.Enemies.Add(enemy);
        Camera.main.GetComponent<Game_Manager>().CreateArrow(i);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timebetweenspawn);  
    }
}
```

`Game_Manager.Enemies` is a static list within `Game_Manager`.

When an enemy is spawned the `Camera.main.GetComponent<Game_Manager>().CreateArrow()` is called, this follows

```
public void CreateArrow(int enemyIndex)
{
        EnemyDetection = new Ray(Player.transform.position, Enemies[enemyIndex].transform.position - Player.transform.position);
        Vector3 raypoint = EnemyDetection.GetPoint(4);
        Vector3 enemydirection = Enemies[enemyIndex].transform.position - Player.transform.position;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(enemydirection);
        GameObject arrow = Instantiate(Arrow, raypoint, rotation) as GameObject;
        arrow.GetComponent<Player_enemyArrow>().enemy = Enemies[enemyIndex];
        print(enemyIndex);
        print(Enemies[enemyIndex].name);
        arrow.name =  Enemies[enemyIndex].name + "Arrow ";
        arrow.transform.SetParent(Player.transform);
        arrow.transform.position = raypoint;    
}
```

this takes the enemy spawned and creates an arrow with the `Player_EnemyArrow` script which handles pointing towards the given enemy and the position of the arrow.

My problem is that the first arrows works fine but when i pass the `CreateArrow(1)` and i of 1 the enemy in that index is enemy0 when it should be enemy1.

Comment: Are you sure that the enemyIndex is the correct size from within `CreateArrow()`?

Comment: "enemyIndex = i" within the SpawnShip Enum

Comment: you must not have "_" underscore character in class names.  you'll have to change 'em all.

Comment: How come? when i say classes i mean C# scripts is that correct?

Comment: @archlord371 no matter what the language it is usually not a good idea to put _ in classes. You can use: .`StationSpawner, GameManager and PlayerEnemyArrow` each first word capitalized.

Comment: Can you [re-word your last sentence](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35780115/edit) to have more information, it is not exactly clear what is going wrong.